# IF signal amplify without delay

Tags: dsp, level-shifting, sampling, scaling

I have a RF Frontend that has an 4 IF signal output (2 I channel and 2 Q channel from 2 receiving anettans). Each channel of the IF has a signal rangining from 1.5V to 3.5V with a DC offset of 2.5V.

#### IF output signal:

[image: IF output signal]

I want to sample the signal with an ADC that has a reference voltage from 0 to 5V and use the mid range of 2.5V for better sampling.

So, I prefer to shift the signal and amplify to make it from 0.5V to 4.5V with a offset of 2.5V.

#### Desired output signal

[image: Desired output signal]

I tried coupled capacitor then level shift and gain with op-amp, also other shifting circuit, but the coupled capacitor to block the DC causes a little phase shift which is not desirable. So I don't want to filter the DC and  amplify to my desired signal. Please suggest me a circuit that will work without delay and phase shift.

Comment: Could you be so kind and give us a hint about the frequency  (ca. 500kHz? according to what I see in the graphs) and BW of your IF signals?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a (big enough) capacitor to AC couple the signal to whatever level you want.

If you want to use the whole voltage range of the ADC you should use some AGC circuit to make sure the amplitude of the signal doesn't vary to much.

Answer (score 0):

Your signal already has a centre voltage of 2.5 volts and you are wanting to amplify the p-p value by 2 to take you from 2.5V +/- 1V to 2.5V +/- 2V.

I really wouldn't bother - any circuit you add is going to amplify noise and signal together so there will be no perceivable SNR benefit and quite possibly there may be a small reduction due to the introduction of this extra circuit.

You are using an ADC input to digitize the IF signals so why bother?

Comment: So you say, to directly sample the signal?

Comment: @dDebug unless you have knowledge unknown to me, I am.

Comment: Iwant to use the complete resolution of the ADC.So here is a LT spice circuit I made to level shift after removing the DC offset.

http://tinypic.com/r/24aye60/8

The signal has very low amplitude now.Can you suggest a circuit to keep the DCoffset at 2.5V andamplify the signal from 0.5v to 4.5V?

Comment: It makes little sense to use the complete resolution because any increase in amplitude will clip the signal in the digital domain.